# How To Preserve path types in value of Shapeless' Witness?

Tags: scala, shapeless

In Shapeless' implementation of `Witness`, it looks like the `value` has type `value: T { }` and I believe this means that if `T` has any path dependent types, they are lost ([reference](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L34)).

For example, suppose I have a type like:

```
trait Field {
  type Out
}
```

I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
def foo[F <: Field](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[F], show: Show[witness.value.Out]) { ... }
```

Is it possible to preserve the path types in a shapeless witness?

background: I'm trying to accomplish [this](https://gist.github.com/aaronlevin/7319af61beb8f4f572388d45d530b324b) and someone suggested [this](https://gist.github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/57c328e5268fe0fef69e5605fcdf70fb). However, their solution doesn't work because `Witness` gives me a unique implicit for each object, whereas with their solution will end up with implicit collisions when two `Field` types have the same paths.